How can I estimate thrust?
I am stuck on an aircraft performance question.
The question seems fairly simple, calculating the ground run between V_0 and V_rotational. I have attempted this a few ways but made the most progress using the average acceleration method. However, I'm still stuck on the fact that I am not provided with a thrust force.
The question outlines that the aircraft is electric, single engine, and propeller driven. Within the question the following values are also given: maximum take-off weight, wing span, wing area, engine power, drag coef, ground factor, and friction coef.
I'm not sure if I'm missing something but I've spent hours online going in circles about how I can get the thrust figure. As it seems to be the only thing I'm missing.
If anyone could nudge me in the right direction that would be great :)
Thanks

Can you show us your try? Anyway this answer should help.

You can calculate $T$ from $V_{TO}$, the shaft power $P_s$, and assuming a propeller efficiency $\eta _ p$, $V_{TO}$ is $1.2V_s$ and $V_s$ is easily calculated. See this example at the end of page 5 "This is a propeller driven aircraft with a shaft (brake) horsepower of 2400 per engine. We want to calculate the minimum ground run". Remember we can't help you if you don't show your own attempt explaining your detailed reasoning.

Is any take-off run data available for a similar aircraft?  Is this a model or full scale?
